# Django error that doesn't make sense

Tags: python, django, command-line

[image]
I am currently working on a Django site, and I am trying to get the login system to work. However I keep on having the same issue, where I get the error message `No modules named 'users.urls'`. However I do have this module in users, so I am not sure what is wrong. There is a fair amount of code, so I won't upload it, but if you need to see anything just ask and I will edit it. 
Thanks very much,
Milo
[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Share your project structure please.

Comment: How do I do that

Comment: Make a screenshot of your project structure and upload it.

Comment: Could you please, share the full traceback of the error?

Comment: Thanks for all your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have since realised that I had forgotten to migrate it - when I restarted the server it worked fine. Thanks very much for all your help!

Comment: Sorry - it says that I have to wait 6 days

Answer (score 0):

just use `import users` at the top of the learnig_logs/urls file.